# How to set this array based on 2 other arrays in Amibroker?

Tags: amibroker

I have these 2 arrays `signal_arr` and `value_arr` in Amibroker. 
From these 2 arrays, I want to output an array `output_arr` such that when `signal_arr` is 1, it will follow the value of `value_arr`. When `signal_arr` is 0, `output_arr` will retain the value of `value_arr` when `signal_arr` was last 1.

This is best illustrated by an example.

```
signal_arr =  [ 1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0 ]
value_arr =   [0.5 0.6 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.2 0.3 0.4]
output_arr =  [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.2 0.2 0.2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ValueWhen`.

```
output_arr =  ValueWhen(signal_arr, value_arr);
```